# tensorflow in java running failed

Tags: java, tensorflow

I follow the instruction of example to install TensorFlow for Java on Windows
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java

When I execute the code:

```
java -cp libtensorflow-1.1.0.jar:. -Djava.library.path=./jni HelloTF
```

it raise the problem

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloTF
```

Here is the file in my folder. I believe it is the problem of defining parameter of -Djava or -cp, but I just cannot really understand how to write those two parameters. 
[image]

Comment: Did this succeed : `javac -cp libtensorflow-1.1.0.jar HelloTF.java`?

Comment: The classpath separator for Windows is `;` not `:` .

Comment: @Exception_al Yes, I can use javac to generate the class file. But I can not run it.

Comment: Did you see @Berger's answer ... Please try with `java -cp libtensorflow-1.1.0.jar;. -Djava.library.path=./jni HelloTF`

Comment: @Berger You are right! but I still get another error " Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: windows...". I think it is the problem that it can not find the jni.dll file. I have tried `-Djava.library.path=./jni` or `-Djava.library.path=jni.dll` and it dosen't work.

Comment: @LISHITING : try setting the java library path to simply `jni` , or to its absolute path if this fails . Note that the `jni` directory should contain the relevant dll .

Comment: @Berger Problem solved. I should simply create a folder named "jni" and put the dll file in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `dll` file in both `jdk` and `jre` as well and jar file too.

In the following:

1. `jdk/bin` paste the `dll` file here
2. `jdk/db/lib` paste the `jar` file here
3. `jdk/jre/bin` paste the `dll` file here
4. `jdk/lib` paste the `jar` file here
5. `jre/bin` paste the `dll` file here
6. `jre/lib` paste the `jar` file here

And, also include the `jar` and `dll` files in the folder in which you are saving your java files.

That should be all that you need to do.